# linkedin api company search results for location

Tags: location, linkedin-api

I can't seem to find this in the documentation, its probably there, I just can't see it.
I make a request like below, but I want to limit the results to a geographical region. Is there a query parameter I can use to do this? Something like location={something}?

https://api.linkedin.com/v1/company-search:(facets,companies:(name,description,square-logo-url,website-url))?keywords=something&oauth2_access_token=xxxxxxx&format=json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked it out.

https://api.linkedin.com/v1/company-search:(facets,companies:(name,description,square-logo-url,website-url,locations))?oauth2_access_token=xxxxxxx&keywords=company+name&facet=location%2Cau%3A0&count=1&format=json

(you can remove the count=1 that was for my purposes)

so basically you would need to use an encoded geographical location code
so in my URl I'm targeting Australia which is au:0 or us:0 for the US.
You can also target a geographical location by changing the 0 to another number you can most of these numbers from [here](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/targeting-company-shares#geos). So us:84 would be the San Francisco Bay Area.

Comment: that list is helpful.  what are you using for codes like 'na.us.wy'.  I have tried everything to get that one na.us.wy, us.wy, us:wy, na:us:wy, but can't get anything back.  This is obviously an outlier as most will be in those major areas of the list that have numerical region codes but annoying nonetheless

Comment: That,s a good question. I haven't been able to decipher some of those.


However if you search for a company you know is in that region and do something like:


echo "<pre>";
var_dump($company);
echo "</pre>";
(or whatever the equivilant is in your language)
After getting rid of the facet=location, part
You'll see the region code listed there somewhere...